# resolution problems with VGA connected monitor

Tags: xorg, vga, xorg.conf

A few days ago, I made a xorg.conf file for a friend whose xserver didn't recognize it's plug and play monitor when connected through the VGA. Strangely, Windows has no problem recognizing it and I think this problem did't happen years ago, so I suppose someone stopped supporting de recognition at some time. I already knew of this problem with a nvidia hardware but in his case, it was intel.

I made an xorg.conf file to solve this, but strangely (again), for 1920x1080 resolution, the picture was clipped to a smaller resolution, and not for e.g. 1600x900, and it was not due to monitor, but to the computer (the monitor supports 1080p and shifting the picture also shifted the clipped border.)

This raises 2 questions :

- Since when (package ? driver ? version ? discussion ?) was the plug
  and play support removed for VGA ?
- what might be the explanation for such a clipping at high resolution ( - I'm sorry, I fear I might not be able to provide the xorg.conf file. I asked him for it, but since he made a re-installation since then, it appears he already lost the xorg.conf I wrote for him -_-" )

Comment: I don't recall PnP VGA monitors ever working automatically under X. One always needed to manually specify a modeline, including refresh rates and resolution. There were tools which would probe the monitor with various resolutions and give you a list of what was theoretically supported, though. As for any "clipping," I can only presume that the mode lines are incorrect for the monitor, and the screen may only do 1080i or need overscan configuration of some sort, or the resolution is simply not supported.

Comment: In fact, you might be right : It is true that at the time I used X on VGA whithout any xorg.conf, it might have been only with monitors limited to 1024x768... I should try to retrieve some of those old installations and make some checks with old version to make sure... :-/